# create personaliced filter in datatable with select

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

i want to create in my datatable one filter personaliced with dropdown but i don´t know where to begin... Sorry it´s my question it´s very bad. I´m reading documentation from datatable reading any forum, and other post from stackoverflow but i don´t know how i can to do.

i need create one filter with this param:

- new
- pending
- null
- confirm
- commercialiced
- confirm-absent
- confirm-null

i need other dropdown filter but if i do the firts o can to do next.

I need create one select personaliced with this data, and after i need create event and function to controller, etc? i´m working in backend with laravel 5.6. Now i have this code:

```
initComplete: function () {
            // bottom filter
            this.api().columns([6,8,9]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        column.search( this.value ).draw();
                    } );
                
                // If I add extra data in my JSON, how do I access it here besides column.data?
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },
```

but this return actual data en my table and create select. I need create select with x option and after to can search data and fill datatable.

Sorry for my question, and thanks for help me

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Where do you want this drop-down list to be placed? In one table footer? Outside of the table? What values do you want the drop-down list to contain? How do the values in the drop-down list relate to the data in the table?

Comment: I think you need to show us some sample data in the table, and then show us what you want to drop-down list to contain. And then explain the relationship between the data in the table and the values in the drop-down list.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks for your help. I updated my question with my solution. I wanted a footer column filter with dropdown and option with list in my question. But i think that i can use same code that i showed in my question for created a new filter personaliced, and "boila"  it´s ok

Comment: OK - great - glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code i can solve my question:

```
initComplete: function () {
            // DATE FILTER
            this.api().columns([3]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        column.search( this.value ).draw();
                    } );
                
                // If I add extra data in my JSON, how do I access it here besides column.data?
                select.append( '<option value="nueva">Nueva</option>'+
                                '<option value="confirmada">Confirmada</option>'+
                                '<option value="pendiente">Pendiente</option>'+
                                '<option value="nula">Nula</option>'+
                                '<option value="aplazada">Aplazada</option>'+
                                '<option value="ausente">Ausente</option>'+
                                '<option value="venta">venta</option>'
                            );
            } );
```

in my question i´m using this code to get all header from my table and created filter. i thinked that i would can use this for created one select in position 3 with my values... And it´s ok